# Getting JSON Array Data into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json

I am extremely confused on how to access this data, and get it into MySQL
I have this JSON Data:

```
{
   "serial_number": "70-b3-d5-1a-00-be",
   "dateTime": "2020-08-14 20:58",
   "passReport": [
      {
         "id": 1,
         "passList": [
            {
               "passType": 1,
               "time": "20:58:38"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I can get **serial_number** & **dateTime** perfectly fine, however I cannot get **passType** & **time** into my database


Here is my code for injesting:

```
//read the json file contents
$jsondata = file_get_contents('php://input');
//convert json object to php associative array
$data = json_decode($jsondata, true);

//mySQL creds & mySQL database & tables
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "my user";
$password = "my pass";
$dbname = "my db";
$serial_number = $data['serial_number'];
$dateTime = $data['dateTime'];
$id = $data['id'];
$passType = $data['passType'];
$time = $data['time'];


// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//Insert into Database Tables
$sql = "INSERT INTO mytable (serial_number, dateTime, passType, time)
VALUES('$serial_number', '$dateTime', '$passType', '$time')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
  echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);


?>
```

I am pretty noobish at PHP, trying to learn! Appreciate any help here. I don't enough knowledge of accessing the data in the array.. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you!!! Thank makes way more sense... This is exactly what I was looking for. I figured as much, but I didnt know how to access that particular array, inside another array. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$data['passType'];` makes no sense. It's clearly not on the same level of the object as serial number, for example.

You need to go down inside the hierarchy of the object. It's inside an array, and then another array.

Try

```
$data["passReport"][0]["passList"][0]['passType']
```

and

```
$data["passReport"][0]["passList"][0]['time']
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
//You can use var_dump to see the structure of decoded json, then you can access.
$jsondata = '{"serial_number":"70-b3-d5-1a-00-be","dateTime":"2020-08-14 20:58","passReport":[{"id":1,"passList":[{"passType":1,"time":"20:58:38"}]}]}';
$jdc = json_decode($jsondata,true);
var_dump($jdc);
var_dump($jdc['passReport'][0]['passList'][0]['passType']);
var_dump($jdc['passReport'][0]['passList'][0]['time']);
?>
```